Very low AUC in the test data while having adequate accuracy on the test data in Random forest model
I am encountering a strange issue where I obtained low AUC = 0.18 on a test data whereas the model I built gave an accuracy of 80.3 on this test data, and sensitivity of 55.5 and specificity of 90.7
I built a model on a training data that have been run through over/undersampling (in ROSE package)
Here what I have done briefly:
My data called "Data2" and the factor variable is "Status" and I am predicting the "mastitis cases" vs "normal" ones.
Explore the data imbalance
table(Data2$Status)
Mastitis   Normal 
      58      293 

Splitting the data :
set.seed(1234)
pd <- sample(2, nrow(Data2), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
Data2_train <- Data2[pd==1,]
Data2_test<- Data2[pd==2,]

table(Data2_train$Status)
Mastitis   Normal 
      40      250 
table(Data2_test$Status)
Mastitis   Normal 
      18       43 

Because this is an obvious imbalance, I tried both oversampling/undersampling
set.seed(1234)
Both_Data2<- ovun.sample(Status~., data = Data2_train, method = "both", p = 0.5, seed = 222, 
                           N = 290)   

Both_sample_train<- Both_Data2$data   
table(Both_sample_train$Status) 
Normal Mastitis 
     135      155 

As you see this created almost balanced classes in the newly formed traingin data
So I will train the model on this data :
After runniogn 10 RF models with variable ntrees and mtry, I found that the model with the best accuracy and lowest OOB on the newly formed traingin data is :
Data3_Both_400<- randomForest(Status~., data = Both_sample_train, ntree = 400, proximity = T, importance = T)

The summary of this model:
Call:
 randomForest(formula = Status ~ ., data = Both_sample_train,      ntree = 400, proximity = T, importance = T) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 400
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 16.21%
Confusion matrix:
         Normal Mastitis class.error
Normal      116       19   0.1407407
Mastitis     28      127   0.1806452

Then I used this model to predict on the test data
Model_pred_test <- predict(Data3_Both_400, Data2_test )
Model_pred_test <- factor(Model_pred_test, levels = levels(Data2_test$Status))
confusionMatrix(Model_pred_test, Data2_test$Status, positive = 'Mastitis')

This gives :
     Reference
Prediction Mastitis Normal
  Mastitis       10      4
  Normal          8     39
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.8033         
                 95% CI : (0.6816, 0.894)
    No Information Rate : 0.7049         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.05737        
                                         
                  Kappa : 0.4945         
                                         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.38648        
                                         
            Sensitivity : 0.5556         
            Specificity : 0.9070         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7143         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8298         
             Prevalence : 0.2951         
         Detection Rate : 0.1639         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.2295         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7313         
                                         
       'Positive' Class : Mastitis 

So the accuracy of this model on the test data was high (80.3), with 55.5% sensitivity.
When runnign ROC on this model:
pred<- predict(Data3_Both_400, Data2_test, type = 'prob') 

This gives:
     Normal  Mastitis
1   0.1125   0.8875
10  0.5250   0.4750
17  0.3200   0.6800
19  0.7825   0.2175
22  0.9925   0.0075
32  0.9925   0.0075
35  0.6800   0.3200
45  0.0850   0.9150
47  0.5750   0.4250
65  0.7625   0.2375
70  0.8175   0.1825
77  0.9925   0.0075
79  0.8975   0.1025
84  0.9925   0.0075
90  0.9925   0.0075
95  0.8350   0.1650
102 0.9925   0.0075
105 0.8350   0.1650
110 0.8350   0.1650
111 0.8350   0.1650
113 0.9925   0.0075
141 0.9925   0.0075
147 0.8350   0.1650
154 0.9925   0.0075
156 0.8350   0.1650
174 0.5675   0.4325
181 0.5000   0.5000
193 0.8800   0.1200
195 0.9000   0.1000
198 0.0800   0.9200
202 0.7675   0.2325
207 0.6075   0.3925
211 0.8425   0.1575
214 0.7450   0.2550
235 0.8750   0.1250


pred<- prediction(pred[,2], Data2_test$Status)

Roc<- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
plot(Roc, colorize = T, 
     main = 'Healthy Vs Mastitis', lwd = 2)
abline(a=0, b=1)

auc<- performance(pred, 'auc')

auc<- unlist(slot(auc, 'y.values'))
auc

This gave an AUC = 0.18, which is low ?
Could you please advice on whether this is a good model or not ? why low AUC in a high accuracy in the test data.
I knew that the test data is imbalanced as shown :
table(Data2_test$Status)
Mastitis   Normal 
      18       43 

I generally observed that the models with lower sensitivity (prediction of mastitis) and no over or under sampling (class imbalance in the training data) have better AUCs (0.7-0.8) compared to the models with higher sensitivity (when I performed over sampling or over/under sampling) (0.1-0.2)
This is confusing.. What is the criteria to define a good model ? is it the predictability on the test data (here mainly sensitivity as I am interested to predict the mastitis cases) OR the model with higher AUC (predicatbility) ?
Could you give a comment on this
Thanks

When you calculate AUC, are you sure it is taking Mastitis as the positive class?
